# Parsing nested JSON and writing it to CSV

Tags: python, json, csv

I'm struggling with this problem. I have a JSON file and needs ti put it out to CSV, its fine if the structure is kind of flat with no deep nested items.

But in this case the nested `RACES` is messing me up.

How would I go about getting the data in a format like this:

```
VENUE, COUNTRY, ITW, RACES__NO, RACES__TIME
```

for each object and each race in the object?

```
{
    "1": {
        "VENUE": "JOEBURG",
        "COUNTRY": "HAE",
        "ITW": "XAD",
        "RACES": {
            "1": {
                "NO": 1,
                "TIME": "12:35"
            },
            "2": {
                "NO": 2,
                "TIME": "13:10"
            },
            "3": {
                "NO": 3,
                "TIME": "13:40"
            },
            "4": {
                "NO": 4,
                "TIME": "14:10"
            },
            "5": {
                "NO": 5,
                "TIME": "14:55"
            },
            "6": {
                "NO": 6,
                "TIME": "15:30"
            },
            "7": {
                "NO": 7,
                "TIME": "16:05"
            },
            "8": {
                "NO": 8,
                "TIME": "16:40"
            }
        }
    },
    "2": {
        "VENUE": "FOOBURG",
        "COUNTRY": "ABA",
        "ITW": "XAD",
        "RACES": {
            "1": {
                "NO": 1,
                "TIME": "12:35"
            },
            "2": {
                "NO": 2,
                "TIME": "13:10"
            },
            "3": {
                "NO": 3,
                "TIME": "13:40"
            },
            "4": {
                "NO": 4,
                "TIME": "14:10"
            },
            "5": {
                "NO": 5,
                "TIME": "14:55"
            },
            "6": {
                "NO": 6,
                "TIME": "15:30"
            },
            "7": {
                "NO": 7,
                "TIME": "16:05"
            },
            "8": {
                "NO": 8,
                "TIME": "16:40"
            }
        }
    }, ...
}
```

I would like to output this to CSV like this:

```
VENUE, COUNTRY, ITW, RACES__NO, RACES__TIME
JOEBERG, HAE, XAD, 1, 12:35
JOEBERG, HAE, XAD, 2, 13:10
JOEBERG, HAE, XAD, 3, 13:40
...
...
FOOBURG, ABA, XAD, 1, 12:35
FOOBURG, ABA, XAD, 2, 13:10
```

So first I get the correct keys:

```
self.keys = self.data.keys()
keys = ["DATA_KEY"]
for key in self.keys:
    if type(self.data[key]) == dict:
        for k in self.data[key].keys():
            if k not in keys:
                if type(self.data[key][k]) == unicode:
                    keys.append(k)
                elif type(self.data[key][k]) == dict:
                    self.subkey = k
                    for sk in self.data[key][k].values():
                        for subkey in sk.keys():
                            subkey = "%s__%s" % (self.subkey, subkey)
                            if subkey not in keys:
                                keys.append(subkey)
```

Then add the data:

But how?

This should be a fun one for you skilled forloopers. `;-)`

Comment: What about [json2csv](https://github.com/evidens/json2csv)?

Comment: I guess I could try that, thanks for the link

Comment: Does this have to be generic? I'd write a format-specific conversion for this.

Comment: Yes its generic, I want to be able to parse any json file like this that has a deep nest like the example

Comment: @Harry: what, any level of nesting?

Comment: No, like the example. So just when a key:value is a dict of the first key:value, not deeper than that

Comment: @Harry: Right, and is the format consistent? E.g., all top-level and nested objects have the same keys, always, for their type?

Comment: Yes, we can asume that. So It will always be parentkey__childkey if that is what you meant

Comment: What happens if there are *multiple* nested objects in each 'venue'? Should you assume they are the same length, or do you write out the *product* the same way your sample rows are the product of 'venue' times 'race' (so venue info is repeated for each race).

Comment: It will follow the same scheme as in my example for races

Comment: Sorry, that isn't clear enough. If there is both a `RACES` and a `ACCIDENTS` entry, and they are not the same length, what should happen? Would you list `venue 1, race 1, accident 1`, then `venue 1, race 1, accident 2`, etc. then `venue 1, race 2, accident 1`, etc.? That is a product expansion. Or would a second nested item have to be the same length so that you can do `venue 1, race 1, accident 1`, then `venue 1, race 2, accident 2`? Or is only *one* nested item supported, so *only* `RACES` or another nested key?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'd collect keys only for the first object, then assume that the rest of the format is consistent.

The following code also limits the nested object to just *one*; you did not specify what should happen when there is more than one. Having two or more nested structures of equal length could work (you'd 'zip' those together), but if you have structures of differing length you need to make an explicit choice how to handle those; zip with empty columns to pad, or to write out the product of those entries (A x B rows, repeating information from A each time you find a B entry).

```
import csv
from operator import itemgetter


with open(outputfile, 'wb') as outf:
    writer = None  # will be set to a csv.DictWriter later

    for key, item in sorted(data.items(), key=itemgetter(0)):
        row = {}
        nested_name, nested_items = '', {}
        for k, v in item.items():
            if not isinstance(v, dict):
                row[k] = v
            else:
                assert not nested_items, 'Only one nested structure is supported'
                nested_name, nested_items = k, v

        if writer is None:
            # build fields for each first key of each nested item first
            fields = sorted(row)

            # sorted keys of first item in key sorted order
            nested_keys = sorted(sorted(nested_items.items(), key=itemgetter(0))[0][1])
            fields.extend('__'.join((nested_name, k)) for k in nested_keys)

            writer = csv.DictWriter(outf, fields)
            writer.writeheader()

        for nkey, nitem in sorted(nested_items.items(), key=itemgetter(0)):
            row.update(('__'.join((nested_name, k)), v) for k, v in nitem.items())
            writer.writerow(row)
```

For your sample input, this produces:

```
COUNTRY,ITW,VENUE,RACES__NO,RACES__TIME
HAE,XAD,JOEBURG,1,12:35
HAE,XAD,JOEBURG,2,13:10
HAE,XAD,JOEBURG,3,13:40
HAE,XAD,JOEBURG,4,14:10
HAE,XAD,JOEBURG,5,14:55
HAE,XAD,JOEBURG,6,15:30
HAE,XAD,JOEBURG,7,16:05
HAE,XAD,JOEBURG,8,16:40
ABA,XAD,FOOBURG,1,12:35
ABA,XAD,FOOBURG,2,13:10
ABA,XAD,FOOBURG,3,13:40
ABA,XAD,FOOBURG,4,14:10
ABA,XAD,FOOBURG,5,14:55
ABA,XAD,FOOBURG,6,15:30
ABA,XAD,FOOBURG,7,16:05
ABA,XAD,FOOBURG,8,16:40
```