# How to convert nested json with same data to CSV python

Tags: python, json

I have json data with nested arrays which contains same key name.
My Json format is like(may vary key value pair names):

```
{
  "name": "bharat",
  "age": 27, 
  "vehicles": [
      {
          "car": "tata",
          "bike": "duke",
          "plane": "n",            
      },
      {
          "car": "odi",
          "bike": "duke",
          "plane": "n",       
      }]
 }
```

I have tried 
 [Convert nested JSON to CSV file in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41180960/convert-nested-json-to-csv-file-in-python) 
but got multiple columns with same keys in vehicles.

My code is

```
import json
import csv
from elasticsearch import Elasticsearch
import elasticsearch.helpers

with open("query.json") as f:
  query=json.load(f)

es = Elasticsearch(['http://xx.xx.xx.xx:xxxx'],verify_certs=False)

results_gen = elasticsearch.helpers.scan(
    es,
    query=query,
    index="demo",
)

def get_leaves(item, key=None):
    if isinstance(item, dict):
        leaves = []

        for i in item.keys():
            leaves.extend(get_leaves(item[i], i))
        return leaves
    elif isinstance(item, list):
        leaves = []
        for i in item:
            leaves.extend(get_leaves(i, key))
        return leaves
    else:
        return [(key, item)]

with  open('Data.csv', 'w', newline='') as f_output:
    csv_output = csv.writer(f_output)
    write_header = True

    for entry in results_gen:
        e=entry['_source']

        leaf_entries = sorted(get_leaves(e))
    print(leaf_entries)
        if write_header:
            csv_output.writerow([k for k, v in leaf_entries])
            write_header = False
        csv_output.writerow([v for k, v in leaf_entries])
```

I am getting output like

```
name    age    car    car  bike   bike plane plane
bharat  27     tata   odi  duke    duke  n     n
```

I expect output to be like

```
name    age    car    bike    plane
bharat  27     tata   duke    n     
bharat  27     odi    duke    n
```

Comment: 1) share your code 2) what is the expected output?

Answer (score 0):

Something like this (Assuming you are interested in vehicles data only)

```
data = {"name": "bharat", "age": 27, "vehicles": [{"car": "tata", "bike": "duke", "plane": "n",
                                                   }, {"car": "odi", "bike": "duke", "plane": "n",
                                                       }]}
with open('out.csv', 'w') as out:
    for v in data['vehicles']:
        line = ','.join(v.values())
        out.write(line + '\n')
```

Comment: I am not sure I understand what is "dynamic". Please explain.

Comment: I am reading data from elastic search so json format will be different means key value pairs will be different.

Comment: The data structure you get from elastic - does it have a well know structure? If the answer is yes - please share it.

Comment: it is same as json format , one as mentioned in question.

Answer (score 0):

You Can use Pandas Normalize class to normalize the json into pandas dataframe and then write the dataframe to csv

Lets say you have Json dictionaries in variable 'data' like: [{json1},{json2},{json3}...]

```
    import json
    import pandas
    from pandas.io.json import json_normalize

    for d in data:
        normalized_data = json_normalize(d)
        normalized_data .to_csv('csv_file_name', sep='|', mode='a', index=False, na_rep='', header=False)
```

refer: https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.io.json.json_normalize.html