# Parsing nested JSON and writing it to CSV (Revisited)

Tags: python, json, python-3.x, csv, export-to-csv

Being new to Python, and given the answer in the following post:

[Parsing nested JSON and writing it to CSV](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20424473/parsing-nested-json-and-writing-it-to-csv)

How do I define the input file for this code to work? I understand that I have to define the "outputfile" as the path/filename that I am writing to, but I just don't know where the input file is supposed to go?

EDIT: Adding for clarity that I have a JSON file for input and wish to convert it to a CSV file as output. I just want to know how to write the code that would take the example (from above) and have it specify a particular JSON file as input. Also for clarity, the name of the JSON file will remain the same however the contents will change daily, so I just need to know where to put the open()
and and how to call it in the script.

EDIT_2:

```
inputfile = "/some/file.json"
outputfile = "/some/file.csv"
with open(inputfile, 'r') as inf:
    with open(outputfile, 'w') as outf:
        writer = None  # will be set to a csv.DictWriter later
            fp = open(inputfile, 'r')
            json_value = fp.read()
            data = json.loads(json_value)

        for key, item in sorted(data.items(), key=itemgetter(0)):
            row = {}
            nested_name, nested_items = '', {}
            for k, v in item.items():
                if not isinstance(v, dict):
                    row[k] = v
                else:
                    assert not nested_items, 'Only one nested structure is supported'
                    nested_name, nested_items = k, v

            if writer is None:
                # build fields for each first key of each nested item first
                fields = sorted(row)

                # sorted keys of first item in key sorted order
                nested_keys = sorted(sorted(nested_items.items(), key=itemgetter(0))[0][1])
                fields.extend('__'.join((nested_name, k)) for k in nested_keys)

                writer = csv.DictWriter(outf, fields)
                writer.writeheader()

            for nkey, nitem in sorted(nested_items.items(), key=itemgetter(0)):
                row.update(('__'.join((nested_name, k)), v) for k, v in nitem.items())
                writer.writerow(row)
```

The error I am getting is...

```
for k, v in item.items():
```

AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'items'

I think I may not be reading the JSON file correctly... Python newbie stressors.

EDIT_3 (updated JSON structure):
Here is one 'entry' from the JSON file I am using (NIST/NVD JSON file):

```
    {
      "CVE_data_type" : "CVE",
      "CVE_data_format" : "MITRE",
      "CVE_data_version" : "4.0",
      "CVE_data_numberOfCVEs" : "6208",
      "CVE_data_timestamp" : "2017-08-14T18:06Z",
      "CVE_Items" : [ {
        "cve" : {
          "CVE_data_meta" : {
            "ID" : "CVE-2003-1547"
          },
          "affects" : {
            "vendor" : {
              "vendor_data" : [ {
                "vendor_name" : "francisco_burzi",
                "product" : {
                  "product_data" : [ {
                    "product_name" : "php-nuke",
                    "version" : {
                      "version_data" : [ {
                        "version_value" : "6.5"
                      }, {
                        "version_value" : "6.5_beta1"
                      }, {
                        "version_value" : "6.5_rc3"
                      }, {
                        "version_value" : "6.5_rc2"
                      }, {
                        "version_value" : "6.5_rc1"
                      } ]
                    }
                  } ]
                }
              } ]
            }
          },
          "problemtype" : {
            "problemtype_data" : [ {
              "description" : [ {
                "lang" : "en",
                "value" : "CWE-79"
              } ]
            } ]
          },
          "references" : {
            "reference_data" : [ {
              "url" : "http://secunia.com/advisories/8478"
            }, {
              "url" : "http://securityreason.com/securityalert/3718"
            }, {
              "url" : "http://www.securityfocus.com/archive/1/archive/1/316925/30/25250/threaded"
            }, {
              "url" : "http://www.securityfocus.com/archive/1/archive/1/317230/30/25220/threaded"
            }, {
              "url" : "http://www.securityfocus.com/bid/7248"
            }, {
              "url" : "https://exchange.xforce.ibmcloud.com/vulnerabilities/11675"
            } ]
          },
          "description" : {
            "description_data" : [ {
              "lang" : "en",
              "value" : "Cross-site scripting (XSS) vulnerability in block-Forums.php in the Splatt Forum module for PHP-Nuke 6.x allows remote attackers to inject arbitrary web script or HTML via the subject parameter."
            } ]
          }
        },
        "configurations" : {
          "CVE_data_version" : "4.0",
          "nodes" : [ {
            "operator" : "OR",
            "cpe" : [ {
              "vulnerable" : true,
              "cpeMatchString" : "cpe:/a:francisco_burzi:php-nuke:6.5",
              "cpe23Uri" : "cpe:2.3:a:francisco_burzi:php-nuke:6.5:*:*:*:*:*:*:*"
            }, {
              "vulnerable" : true,
              "cpeMatchString" : "cpe:/a:francisco_burzi:php-nuke:6.5_beta1",
              "cpe23Uri" : "cpe:2.3:a:francisco_burzi:php-nuke:6.5_beta1:*:*:*:*:*:*:*"
            }, {
              "vulnerable" : true,
              "cpeMatchString" : "cpe:/a:francisco_burzi:php-nuke:6.5_rc1",
              "cpe23Uri" : "cpe:2.3:a:francisco_burzi:php-nuke:6.5_rc1:*:*:*:*:*:*:*"
            }, {
              "vulnerable" : true,
              "cpeMatchString" : "cpe:/a:francisco_burzi:php-nuke:6.5_rc2",
              "cpe23Uri" : "cpe:2.3:a:francisco_burzi:php-nuke:6.5_rc2:*:*:*:*:*:*:*"
            }, {
              "vulnerable" : true,
              "cpeMatchString" : "cpe:/a:francisco_burzi:php-nuke:6.5_rc3",
              "cpe23Uri" : "cpe:2.3:a:francisco_burzi:php-nuke:6.5_rc3:*:*:*:*:*:*:*"
            } ]
          } ]
        },
        "impact" : {
          "baseMetricV2" : {
            "cvssV2" : {
              "vectorString" : "(AV:N/AC:M/Au:N/C:N/I:P/A:N)",
              "accessVector" : "NETWORK",
              "accessComplexity" : "MEDIUM",
              "authentication" : "NONE",
              "confidentialityImpact" : "NONE",
              "integrityImpact" : "PARTIAL",
              "availabilityImpact" : "NONE",
              "baseScore" : 4.3
            },
            "severity" : "MEDIUM",
            "exploitabilityScore" : 8.6,
            "impactScore" : 2.9,
            "obtainAllPrivilege" : false,
            "obtainUserPrivilege" : false,
            "obtainOtherPrivilege" : false,
            "userInteractionRequired" : true
          }
        },
        "publishedDate" : "2003-12-31T05:00Z",
        "lastModifiedDate" : "2017-08-08T01:29Z"
      }]
}
```

I would like the keys to be the headers (like lastModifiedDate, cpe23Uri, etc) for the CSV file. I can filter out white space and select just the columns I want once I have the headers and data in the CSV file.

Comment: @MartjinPieters... you answered the linked question... can you answer this one too? :p

Comment: That question assumes you already have the data in a list, you can get the data any way you want. It doesn't have to come from an input file, it can come from calculations that you perform.

Comment: If you want to get it from another file, just write code to open that file and parse it in whatever way is appropriate.

Comment: It's not shown in the linked question or answer, but I think the assumption is the JSON data has been loaded into a Python dictionary named `data`. That could have been done with something like `data = json.load(fp)` where `fp` is a `.read()`-supporting file-like object containing the JSON document.

Comment: @martineau - thanks for the guidance. I'm now getting an error. Posting it above.

Comment: Apparently your JSON data is a JSON array of elements instead of JSON Object (see <http://json.org>). Without know it's exact structure I can't give you additional advice—the linked question & answer are all geared towards processing JSON data in the format shown in the question which different from what you apparently have. [Edit] your question and add a sample of the JSON data you're trying to process to it—just enough to show its structure, not the whole thing if it's large.

Comment: @martineau - I have added the jSON sample data so that you can see the structure.

Comment: @martineau - I went to the json.org link and I indeed have an array, not an object. I also noticed that in some cases one key has multiple values ("cpe23Uri") which all need to be captured.

Comment: How one solves this sort of problem depends in a major way on the structure of the JSON data being processed. Unfortunately the snippet you added to your question (thanks) isn't enough context. What's needed should show things from the outermost level down to at least the one(s) you want to process—showing a single 'entry' out of context isn't enough information. Related to all that is the fact that there's only one instance of the value "cpe23Uri" shown, so I can't tell if that occurring more than once is an issue or not. You also need to describe the format of the CSV file you want.

Comment: The JSON used as an example is not valid JSON. Run it through [JSON Lint](https://jsonlint.com)

Comment: Thanks @dawg, and I can see the error when I put the sample in and hit the "Validate JSON" button. The way it is is the way it comes from NIST (National Institute of Standards and Technology).

Comment: @martineau - updated the sample. Hopefully that is good enough to show what the structure is, even though as dawg points out the structure is flawed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fortunately your JSON data is valid enough for `json.load()` to read and parse....but just saying you would like the keys to be the headers isn't specific enough—there's lots of them at different levels of each 'entry' (as you'll see below). Note how the OP of the linked question defined not only the input but also specifically how the data in it was to be mapped to columns of values in a CSV file with a format that is also shown—not just some hand-waving about mapping keys to file-headers.

Regardless, here's something that may help you do that. It will read each 'entry' in the list associated with the top-level `"CVE_Items"` key in the JSON object you're reading and print it out formatted nicely. From the output you should be able to pick out what columns you want to extract and write as rows to the CSV file and can fill-in the code for doing that.

```
import json

inputfile = "some_file.json"
outputfile = "some_file.csv"

with open(outputfile, 'w', newline='') as outf:
    with open(inputfile, 'r') as fp:
        data = json.load(fp)

    # Here is where you should convert each entry into a row of CSV data.
    # All this does now is show the contents of each entry in "CVE_Items" list.
    for entry in data["CVE_Items"]:
        print(json.dumps(entry, indent=4))
```

Output for the single entry in the sample JSON data you added to your question:

```
{
    "cve": {
        "CVE_data_meta": {
            "ID": "CVE-2003-1547"
        },
        "affects": {
            "vendor": {
                "vendor_data": [
                    {
                        "vendor_name": "francisco_burzi",
                        "product": {
                            "product_data": [
                                {
                                    "product_name": "php-nuke",
                                    "version": {
                                        "version_data": [
                                            {
                                                "version_value": "6.5"
                                            },
                                            {
                                                "version_value": "6.5_beta1"
                                            },
                                            {
                                                "version_value": "6.5_rc3"
                                            },
                                            {
                                                "version_value": "6.5_rc2"
                                            },
                                            {
                                                "version_value": "6.5_rc1"
                                            }
                                        ]
                                    }
                                }
                            ]
                        }
                    }
                ]
            }
        },
        "problemtype": {
            "problemtype_data": [
                {
                    "description": [
                        {
                            "lang": "en",
                            "value": "CWE-79"
                        }
                    ]
                }
            ]
        },
        "references": {
            "reference_data": [
                {
                    "url": "http://secunia.com/advisories/8478"
                },
                {
                    "url": "http://securityreason.com/securityalert/3718"
                },
                {
                    "url": "http://www.securityfocus.com/archive/1/archive/1/316925/30/25250/threaded"
                },
                {
                    "url": "http://www.securityfocus.com/archive/1/archive/1/317230/30/25220/threaded"
                },
                {
                    "url": "http://www.securityfocus.com/bid/7248"
                },
                {
                    "url": "https://exchange.xforce.ibmcloud.com/vulnerabilities/11675"
                }
            ]
        },
        "description": {
            "description_data": [
                {
                    "lang": "en",
                    "value": "Cross-site scripting (XSS) vulnerability in block-Forums.php in the Splatt Forum module for PHP-Nuke 6.x allows remote attackers to inject arbitrary web script or HTML via the subject parameter."
                }
            ]
        }
    },
    "configurations": {
        "CVE_data_version": "4.0",
        "nodes": [
            {
                "operator": "OR",
                "cpe": [
                    {
                        "vulnerable": true,
                        "cpeMatchString": "cpe:/a:francisco_burzi:php-nuke:6.5",
                        "cpe23Uri": "cpe:2.3:a:francisco_burzi:php-nuke:6.5:*:*:*:*:*:*:*"
                    },
                    {
                        "vulnerable": true,
                        "cpeMatchString": "cpe:/a:francisco_burzi:php-nuke:6.5_beta1",
                        "cpe23Uri": "cpe:2.3:a:francisco_burzi:php-nuke:6.5_beta1:*:*:*:*:*:*:*"
                    },
                    {
                        "vulnerable": true,
                        "cpeMatchString": "cpe:/a:francisco_burzi:php-nuke:6.5_rc1",
                        "cpe23Uri": "cpe:2.3:a:francisco_burzi:php-nuke:6.5_rc1:*:*:*:*:*:*:*"
                    },
                    {
                        "vulnerable": true,
                        "cpeMatchString": "cpe:/a:francisco_burzi:php-nuke:6.5_rc2",
                        "cpe23Uri": "cpe:2.3:a:francisco_burzi:php-nuke:6.5_rc2:*:*:*:*:*:*:*"
                    },
                    {
                        "vulnerable": true,
                        "cpeMatchString": "cpe:/a:francisco_burzi:php-nuke:6.5_rc3",
                        "cpe23Uri": "cpe:2.3:a:francisco_burzi:php-nuke:6.5_rc3:*:*:*:*:*:*:*"
                    }
                ]
            }
        ]
    },
    "impact": {
        "baseMetricV2": {
            "cvssV2": {
                "vectorString": "(AV:N/AC:M/Au:N/C:N/I:P/A:N)",
                "accessVector": "NETWORK",
                "accessComplexity": "MEDIUM",
                "authentication": "NONE",
                "confidentialityImpact": "NONE",
                "integrityImpact": "PARTIAL",
                "availabilityImpact": "NONE",
                "baseScore": 4.3
            },
            "severity": "MEDIUM",
            "exploitabilityScore": 8.6,
            "impactScore": 2.9,
            "obtainAllPrivilege": false,
            "obtainUserPrivilege": false,
            "obtainOtherPrivilege": false,
            "userInteractionRequired": true
        }
    },
    "publishedDate": "2003-12-31T05:00Z",
    "lastModifiedDate": "2017-08-08T01:29Z"
}
```

Comment: thank you for that code. I can print as you show above. How do I flatten this into a row that I can write to a CSV file?

Comment: I don't know how to flatten it. As I said, in the linked question, the OP specified how the various parts of the JSON data were to be turned into CSV rows. JSON is a mostly a tree data structure, whereas CSV is a table (or 2D array/matrix) and the mapping from one to the other is arbitrary. I can't decide how to do that part for you—but if you could at least define what you want, I could probably show you how to implement it. One very important detail is how does something that has multiple values associated with it, like `"version_data"`, get turned into a single row.

Comment: It seems that the data in the JSON file is in a key:value pair, sometimes with more than one value for the given key, as in" version_data:" above. I want to have the "key" part of the pair be the header for the column and the "value"(s) fill in the column as data. In the case of multiple values for a key I need to concatenate all values for the given key.

Comment: Perhaps the simplest way to describe what you want would be for you to [edit] your question and show the single CSV row you want created from the single 'entry' in the sample JSON data.

Comment: I can neither add the CSV row in the question I posed above (not enough reputation points), nor can I make it a comment (too long by several thousand characters). Any suggestions?

Comment: Several thousand characters sounds scary...and possibly too broad for a stackoverflow question (regardless of your rep). Anyway, you can try putting the information into a public text document on something like [Pastebin](https://pastebin.com/) and then add a link to it to your question. I may not get around to updating my answer or posting another comment right away, as I've already spent a lot of time here today.